# VBA Code to copy data from four source workbooks to master workbook based on last row that was not previously copied

Tags: excel, vba, office365, vba7

I have a challenge on achieving the below project, kindly please assist:

- I have four **source workbooks** with names(**GK,SK,RJ and TB**).
- Each workbook(GK,SK,RJ and TB) have three worksheets with the same names(**products, channels, and sales**).
- I have **destination workbook** called **consolidated workbook** with the same worksheets names(**products, channels, and sales**) like those of the four source workbooks.
- All workbooks(source + destinations) are in the same folder.
- Iam requesting VBA code that will copy data from each worksheet of all the four source workbooks and transfer/paste the data to worksheets in consolidated workbook based on the rows that were not previously copied from the last copy event.
- Currently I have the below code but whenever I ran it copies everything from worksheets on the source workbooks and paste to worksheets in consolidated workbook which result to duplicated data.
- All the source workbook have worksheets with the "DATE" as a first column in each worksheet table column.
- Destination workbook also have the same worksheet names and the same columns structure on each worksheet are the same as of those source worksheet.
- Kindly advise what should I amend so that the code will that will copy data from each worksheet of all the **four source workbooks** and transfer/paste the data to **worksheets** in **consolidated workbook** based on the rows that were not previously copied from the last copy event.

```
Sub Copy_From_All_Workbooks()
    Dim wb As String, i As Long, sh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wb = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*")
    Do Until wb = ""
        If wb <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wb
                For Each sh In Workbooks(wb).Worksheets
                        sh.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy   '<---- Assumes 1 header row
                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Next sh
            Workbooks(wb).Close False
        End If
        wb = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

- **Kindly please see the amended code:**

```
    Sub Copy_From_All_Workbooks()
    Dim wb As String, i As Long, sh As Worksheet, fndRng As Range, 
    start_of_copy_row As Long, end_of_copy_row As Long, range_to_copy As 
    Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wb = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*")
    Do Until wb = ""
    If wb <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
         Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wb
            For Each sh In Workbooks(wb).Worksheets
            On Error Resume Next
            sh.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy   '<---- Assumes 1 header row
            Set fndRng = sh.Range("A:A").Find(date_to_find,LookIn:=xlValues, 
        searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
                
                If Not fndRng Is Nothing Then
                    start_of_copy_row = fndRng.Row + 1
                   Else
                   start_of_copy_row = 2 ' assuming row 1 has a header you want to ignore
                 End If

                   end_of_copy_row = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                   Set range_to_copy = Range(start_of_copy_row & ":" & end_of_copy_row)
                        
                        latest_date_loaded = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Range("A:A"))
                
                       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
                   On Error GoTo 0
                   
                   Application.CutCopyMode = False
                   
                Next sh
            Workbooks(wb).Close False
        End If
        wb = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

Kindly please see how **consolidated workbook** appear(the sheet names and column format are exactly the same as of the source workbooks.)

[CONSOLIDATED WORKBOOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRvyh.png)

Comment: How would you expect it to detect what came from where? Are there keys in the data to allow that?

Comment: All the four source workbooks(GK,SK,RJ, and TB) have 3 worksheets data of which the first column on each worksheet start with DATE as a first column.

Comment: Also, destination workbook have the same worksheet names and same data structure (column names on each worksheet is on the same format as of the source workbook).

Comment: @CLR does the above clarifies?

Comment: *If* the four source sheet's dates are all in sync, then it sounds like you just want to find the latest ( `Max` ) date in your consolidated worksheet and then only load lines from the four source files where the date of each row is later than the found Max date. If not, you'd need build a 'key' for each row of your sheets and compare them against each other.

Comment: Or.. load them **all** each time and then de-dupe the sheet. A simpler method, provided the total volume of rows never reaches the maximum for a sheet.

Comment: What I kindly request here is that when I run a vba code in consolidated workbook, it should go and copy all data from the four source workbooks(GK, SK,RJ and TB- each of this workbook have 3 worksheets) and paste them into CONSOLIDATED workbooks - worksheets(same worksheets name as the source workbook) based on the current added rows from the source workbooks - worksheets.

Comment: Ah, so there are four source books, and four destination books. Sorry, when I saw 'consolidated' I incorrectly assumed it was just one destination book. So for each sheet, instead of the `sh.UsedRange.offset..` - you'll need to build a range that starts at the first date after your destinations latest date down to the bottom and the rest of your code would probably suffice.

Comment: Oh my friend @CLR , there are four source workbooks with 3 worksheet on each of the workbook. There is only one Consolidated workbook but have 3 worksheets with the same name and column structure like those of the source worksheet column structure.

Comment: The principle still stands, you just have to cycle through each tab as well (which your code already does). Unless you get *very* lucky on this site, the code won't be written for you. You need to have a go yourself and see what you can achieve. Then when you hit an error or problem, post the new code, explain the error you're seeing and someone will guide you through resolving it.

Comment: Thank you @CLR however I am still a VBA learner, and I have a project I want to deliver.  I found the above code somewhere else on the internet. Actually, my problem is only on the way it copies data from source to destination, please see code line 9 how can I ammend it: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: That line **pastes** whatever you've copied onto the bottom of an already part-used worksheet. I would imagine you don't want to change that part at all. The part you want to change is the range that is **copied**. I'll give you some code to help, you'll need to work it into your code though.

Answer (score 0):

The following line can be used to find the latest date loaded on your consolidated sheet:

```
latest_date_loaded = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Range("A:A"))
```

The following lines can be used on a worksheet (`sh`) to create a range (for copying) that starts after the `latest_date_loaded` down to the bottom of the table. You'll therefore need to ensure this is in date order.

```
Dim fndRng As Range, start_of_copy_row As Long, end_of_copy_row As Long, range_to_copy As Range

date_to_find = latest_date_loaded


Set fndRng = sh.Range("A:A").Find(date_to_find, LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

If Not fndRng Is Nothing Then
    start_of_copy_row = fndRng.Row + 1
Else
    start_of_copy_row = 2 ' assuming row 1 has a header you want to ignore
End If

end_of_copy_row = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set range_to_copy = Range(start_of_copy_row & ":" & end_of_copy_row)
```

**EDIT**

Here is a rework of your code, using some of the lines/ideas I've mentioned above.

```
Sub Copy_From_All_Workbooks()
    
    'declarations 
    Dim wb As String, i As Long, sh As Worksheet, fndRng As Range, _
    start_of_copy_row As Long, end_of_copy_row As Long, range_to_copy As _
    Range, latest_date_loaded As Date, consolidated_wb As Workbook
    
    'turn off screen updating for user experience
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'set a reference to the consolidated workbook
    Set consolidated_wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'read parent folder of consolidated workbook
    wb = Dir(consolidated_wb.Path & "\*")
    
    'perform this loop until no more files
    Do Until wb = ""
    
        'make sure it doesn't try to open consolidated workbook (again)
        If wb <> consolidated_wb.Name Then
        
            'open found source workbook
            Workbooks.Open consolidated_wb.Path & "\" & wb
            
            'cycle through each sheet (sh)
            For Each sh In Workbooks(wb).Worksheets
                
                'on that sheet, find the latest date already existing
                latest_date_loaded = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(consolidated_wb.Sheets(sh.Name).Range("A:A"))

                'find the last occurence of that date in column A
                Set fndRng = sh.Range("A:A").Find(latest_date_loaded, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
                
                'if you find that date already then..
                If Not fndRng Is Nothing Then
                    'set the top row to where you found it, plus one
                    start_of_copy_row = fndRng.Row + 1
                Else
                    'otherwise, it's a new sheet, start on row two
                    start_of_copy_row = 2 ' assuming row 1 has a header you want to ignore
                End If
                
                'find the end of the table, using column A's contents
                end_of_copy_row = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                
                'make sure there's something to copy
                If end_of_copy_row >= start_of_copy_row Then
                
                    'create a reference to the block of cells to copy
                    Set range_to_copy = sh.Range(start_of_copy_row & ":" & end_of_copy_row)
                    
                    'copy that range
                    range_to_copy.Copy
                    
                    'paste them, values only
                    consolidated_wb.Sheets(sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    
                    'clear copy markings from screen
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Else
                
                    'otherwise, do nothing here
                    
                End If
                
            Next sh
            
            'close the source workbook
            Workbooks(wb).Close False
        End If
        
        'get next potential filename
        wb = Dir
        
    Loop

    'turn back on screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @CLR Thank you so much for your response, however I need clarity: Where do I add the above lines of code? On the previous codes that I have shared earlier or?

Comment: Currently the code that I previously shared I run it on CONSOLIDATED WORKBOOK STANDARD MODULE.

Comment: Yes, you need to work it into your `Copy_From_All_Workbooks` code.

Comment: I run the below code but it just do the same, it copies everything from the source workbooks - worksheets to destination workbook - worksheets. It doesn't copy based on rows that have not been copied from the last copy event from the source workbook to destination.

Comment: I was trying to paste the code here on the comment but since it's too long, I have shared the ammended code on my first message body above. Please advise what should I rectify.

Comment: I've added a version of your code with my lines worked into it (and a few amendments). I've tested this and it seems to work - but I can't guarantee that as I can't see your data.

Comment: To further improve the code, you may want to consider what would happen if one of the source workbooks contains a worksheet name that doesn't exist in your consolidated wb. Maybe that can't happen, but if it somehow did, then you would probably want to deal with it by either creating the sheet and allowing the program to run, or just copy the sheet over entirely. If you do go down that route and need help - raise a new question.

Comment: Thank you @CLR.  I run the above code it does the same, copying everything in all of the four workbooks - worksheets and pasting to consolidated workbook - worksheets. What I noticed is that may be my explanations are not clear. The 4 workbooks are updated on daily basis meaning data are captured on those workbooks on daily basis , and the code is run on the consolidated workbook in order to copy everything that has been updated from the four workbooks and paste them in consolidated workbook. The issue is that when the code is run on daily basis, it start copying everything and not added data.

Comment: Please see above image of how CONSOLIDATED WORKBOOK appear.

Comment: The code when run here is only taking new data from each tab - so is working as required. If it's taking all the data each time, then the search part must not be working. I guess that might be due to your source data column A not containing 'real' dates perhaps?

Comment: I does contain dates. I have shared an image of how the workbooks and worksheet appear.

Comment: That's almost identical to my test workbook. I can't understand why the code behaves differently for you. I'd suggest using standard vba debugging techniques - i.e. stepping (F8) through the lines of code, watching what happens and 'watching'/hovering over variable names to see what they hold to work out why it's not working.

Comment: I noticed the above when I hover over variable names on the latest date loaded looks like it returns TIME value.

Comment: What I noticed when I hover over latest date loaded it SHOWS = 12:00:00 A.M.